# XSD problem with complexType set abstract="true"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

Thank you! @Yitzhak Khabinsky I copy a small example as below:

In XSD file defined as blow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    vc:minVersion="1.1"
>   
    <xs:element name="CalculationProcess">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CalculationStep" type="CalculationStepType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="UniqueId">
            <xs:selector xpath="CalculationStep"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@Id" />
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="CalculationStepType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Parameter">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="AdditionalData" type="AddData" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:alternative test="@Type = 'Woodham'" type="AddDataWoodham"/>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required" inheritable="true">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"></xs:minInclusive>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" inheritable="true" />
        <xs:attribute name="Type" type="TCalculationStepType" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="InputCount" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="OutputCount" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
        <!-- StreamId must > 0 -->
        <xs:attribute name="StreamId" use="required" >
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <!-- CalculationStep@Type must match one of the enumerations -->
    <xs:simpleType name="TCalculationStepType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Woodham" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:complexType name="AddData" abstract="true"/>
       
    <xs:complexType name="AddDataWoodham">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension  base="AddData">
                <!--PhotostereoWoodham-->
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="FilePath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="ScaleFactorP" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="ScaleFactorQ" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="CalculationMethod" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="SlantLookupSize" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="TiltLookupSize" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension >
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<CalculationProcess xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ObjCalcConfig.xsd">
    <CalculationStep Id='0' Name='Woodham' Type='Woodham' InputCount='4' OutputCount='3' StreamId='1'>
        <Parameter>
            <AdditionalData>
                <FilePath>files\matrix.xml</FilePath>
                <ScaleFactorP>1.5</ScaleFactorP>
                <ScaleFactorQ>1.5</ScaleFactorQ>
                <CalculationMethod>2</CalculationMethod>
                <SlantLookupSize>25</SlantLookupSize>
                <TiltLookupSize>72</TiltLookupSize>
            </AdditionalData>
        </Parameter>
    </CalculationStep>
</CalculationProcess>
```

But I get a error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pmMT.png)

I don't know where is the problem, could someone please help me to resolve this error. THANK YOU!!!

I tried do abstract="false", that doesn't work because the base element  is empty...

Comment: Error Message from XMLSpy:
File C:\Projekt\Wacker\WackerGrabenerkennung_RT\libAnalyze\xmlvalidation\ObjCalcConfig.xml is not valid.
Complex type definition 'AddData' of element <AdditionalData> must have abstract='false'.
Error location: CalculationProcess / CalculationStep / Parameter / AdditionalData
cvc-type.2: Complex type definition 'AddData' of element <AdditionalData> must have abstract='false'.
cvc-elt.5: The element <AdditionalData> is not valid with respect to the actual type definition 'AddData'.

Comment: I see that you are using "Conditional Type Alternative", but `@Type` attribute is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Your type alternative rules are saying that if `@Type` is "Woodham", then the element should have type `AddDataWoodham`; if the `Type` attribute is absent or has any other value (which is the case for your example), then the element should have type `AddData`; but an element cannot have type `AddData` because the type is abstract. So that's clearly an error.

Your instance seems to conform to type `AddDataWoodham`, but it isn't being validated against that type, because it doesn't have a `Type` attribute with value `Woodham`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I edited this question again and copied a small example, can you please check it again for me?

Comment: It has exactly the same problem. Your element has no `Type` attribute, so the default type becomes `AddData`, and it can't take that type because it is abstract.

Comment: The 'Type' Attribute is defined in line 41:
<xs:attribute name="Type" type="TCalculationStepType" use="required" />
Thank you!

Comment: OK, I see you've changed the example. But the `Type` attribute is on the wrong element: the `xs:alternative` is looking for a `Type` attribute on the `AdditionalData` element.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to get the value of 'Type' from the parent (CalculationStep) node?

Comment: I had to look this one up. There is a mechanism called "inheritable attributes" that should fit the bill. There's an example at https://github.com/w3c/xsdtests/blob/master/saxonData/CTA/cta0009.xsd and https://github.com/w3c/xsdtests/blob/master/saxonData/CTA/cta0009.v01.xml

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! Problem resolved.